# C# connecting to local SQL Server database with server's username and password

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I am trying to build a custom connection string that would log in the user to a specific SQL Server user. I have tried many variations of the connection string but nothing works. here is the function.

Server license - developer

- Server type  : Local
- Database     : NLHospital
- Credentials  : passed from the function

Crashes at the `db.open()`; statement.

Made a try catch around it and got this error message

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
    public string LoginAndGetRole(string username, string password)
    {
        using (SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(@"Server=(local)\NLHospital;Integrated Security=false;user id=" + username + ";password=" + password))
        {
            using (SqlCommand getRole = new SqlCommand("findUserRole", db))
            {

                db.Open(); //crashes at this line
                getRole.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                getRole.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Username", username));
                SqlDataReader reader = getRole.ExecuteReader();

            }
            db.Close();
            return "";
        }
    }
```

EDIT :
1) My SQL server was configured ONLY for Windows Authentication.

Comment: IIRC this is usually a firewall issue, or you haven't enabled the right protocols in Sql Server Configuration Manager

Comment: Do the same credentials work when you use SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Try localhost instead of (local)

Comment: @chamara You are right, it seems my created users on the database side are unable to login through management studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=NLHospital; Integrated Security=false;user id=" + username + ";password=" + password)
```

or

```
SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=NLHospital; Integrated Security=false;user id=" + username + ";password=" + password)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your connection string is wrong. You should specify your database name in "Initial Catalog" or in "Database".

Please check sample connection strings at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your Connection string format is wrong. Pls try below format with your parameters.Initial Catalog is your data base name.

= "Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=;Password=;

Answer (score 0):

First, please check the NLHospital is your database instance name? or your database name?

Here is an example to you.

```
Data Source=ServerName\InstanceName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```